How is the secrecy of counted votes results maintained when counting ballots ahead of election day?
Recently read an article that the head voting clerk of a county (not Pennsylvania, as per comment, Wisconsin?) has opted out of tallying up early ballots ahead of election day.  The article went into some details about the impact to delaying election results, the state allowing this to happen, etc... but generally made it very clear that this county was the exception and that other counties had done as suggested and gotten a head start.
Which brings me to my question.
We know there are psychological effects such as "momentum" and "following the herd" that could come into play if voters who had not yet voted knew, or thought they knew, the running tally of electoral results.  That's why some countries (France) just block detailed reporting of anything till the election is over.  And generally speaking, you only ever hear of "exit polls" while voting is still taking place and numbers only start coming out when booths close in a given area.
So, if early counts are happening at scale, how are the results kept secret?  Is it technological - the machines just swallow the ballots and keep results to themselves?  Is it by dint of legal threat:  severe punishment for breaking confidentiality?  Professionalism and ethics? (but we've seen a - small - number of polling clerks doing unethical stuff lately to boost one side or the other's claims)

Surely it includes counting staff being told to keep any knowledge they may gain confident. That is the very least one could do which doesn't cost a thing. One sure was is of course waiting with the counting and guarding the ballot boxes in the meantime.

Wouldn't be in PA. State law there prevents any absentee counting ahead of election day itself.

The ballots that reach the counting phase are segregated from identifying information before the counters (or machine counters) see the ballots.
The results are kept secret until the voting is done. This is a combination of holding the people counting the ballots to secrecy, keeping information in counting "black boxes" (for example, in a machine ballot counter's memory that can't be accessed until the polls are closed), and denying all but a handful of ballot counting officials access to the overall totals. Other election administration officials know only about the lots of ballots that they are dealing with, which are almost always unrepresentative, since they come from the same geographic locations within the election administration district (usually, a county). And, even if there is a leak, it can be plausibly denied any credibility for a few hours or days until the true results are released.
Also, since vote counting is decentralized at the county or city or other district level, vote total for a whole state or even a whole congressional district can't be known from a single leak.
Compromised data from exit polls, which are bound to secrecy by professional journalistic ethics, rather than by law, would be much easier.

Would there be legal risk for a media company to report such leaks if they happened, considering that the leak itself is clearly illegal?  And would you say that the futility of leaking county-level results is a major factor?  You list that, along with other safeguards, but we have seen prosecution of several electoral officials for gross malfeasance since 2020, so there are people with sufficient access to the systems to leak stuff, yet this not happening in this case.

@ItalianPhilosopher No. The Pentagon Papers case clarified that the media company is legally allowed to report an illegal leak even if the person leaking the information can be punished. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon_Papers

"And would you say that the futility of leaking county-level results is a major factor?" In statewide races, probably yes. But honestly, in cases where, e.g., 75% of a Congressional District is in one county, I don't know that I could offer anything more than speculation. Election malfeasance is a more rural than urban phenomena, however, so lots of key races are multi-county and not many single county races are close in rural areas.

In the case of the Pentagon Papers was that because the information was of public interest?  Or just a general defense of the 1st amendment?  i.e. is a media company just as shielded if it publishes "illegal info" of zero, or negative public interest?  Information that is otherwise legally confidential. I can't, for example see media reporting the contents of nuclear technology leaks without risk.

@ItalianPhilosopher Nothing is ever absolute, but illegally disclosed information of arguably no public interest (although if that was really true the media company wouldn't publish it) in which the illegal discloser is not doing so as an agent of the media company solicited in the first place by it to do that, are pretty much completely immune from liability. The hot issue is the extent to which there is a legally enforceable duty of a reporter to disclose a confidential informant.

@ItalianPhilosopher The structure of the nuclear secrets law is also different from the structure of most other government secrecy laws. It is illegal to have nuclear secrets in your possession, if you are not an authorized official, regardless of how you obtained them. In contrast, most government secrecy laws prohibit people with access to certain information from sharing it with people who are not authorized to receive it.
